# Template template and CRTP: compiler bugs, and GCC and clang do not agree

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, crtp, compiler-bug

Consider the following code, in C++11, tested with `g++-6`, `g++-7`, `clang++-3.8` and `clang++-4.0`

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>

// Base 0
template <class T, template <class, T...> class Derived>
struct base0 {
    void operator=(int) {std::cout << "base0::operator=\n";}
};

// Base 1
template <class T, int N, template <class, T...> class Derived>
struct base1 {
    void operator=(int) {std::cout << "base1::operator=\n";}
};

// Derived 0
template <class T, int N>
struct derived0: base0<int, derived0> {
    using base0::operator=;                     // g++6/7 = SUCCESS, clang++-3.8/4.0 = SUCCESS
    using base0<int, derived0>::operator=;      // g++6/7 = SUCCESS, clang++-3.8/4.0 = ERROR
};

// Derived 1
template <class T, int N>
struct derived1: base1<int, N, derived1> {
    using base1::operator=;                     // g++6/7 = ERROR, clang++-3.8/4.0 = ERROR
    using base1<int, N, derived1>::operator=;   // g++6/7 = SUCCESS, clang++-3.8/4.0 = ERROR
};

// Main
int main()
{
    derived0<int, 3> object0;
    derived1<int, 3> object1;
    object0 = 42;
    object1 = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ and clang++ do not produce errors with the same version of the using `base::operator=`. Which one of them is right, and what does the C++ standard say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Clang not implementing [DR1004](https://wg21.link/CWG1004) and hence not allowing the injected-class-name of `derived0/1` to be used as a *template-name*.

GCC's handling of your code appears to be correct in all cases. The difference between 0 and 1 is due to the base being nondependent in 0 but dependent in 1. In the former case name lookup for `base0` finds its injected-class-name which can be validly used as a type name. In the latter case, name lookup skips the dependent base and finds the `::base1` template instead.